# C# context menu for flowlayout panel

Tags: c#, contextmenu, flowlayoutpanel

I use flowlayout panel for dynamically create labels. So I want to use righ click menu for this dynamic created labels but contextmenustrip just recognize flowlayoutpanel. For example I right click and get label.text but couldnt. Is there any way for right click menu for dynamic objects?

```
  Label addlabel(int i)
    {
        Label L = new Label();
        L.Name = "LBL" + i.ToString();
        L.Text = "LBL" + i.ToString();
        L.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        L.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        L.Width = 94;
        L.Height = 21;
        L.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        L.Margin = new Padding(5);

        return L;

    }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label L = addlabel(i);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(L);
          
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure...just set the [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip?view=netcore-3.1) property of the Labels as you create them:

```
L.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

If you want to get the Label that was the "source" of the menu, then use code like this:

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl is Label)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;
        MessageBox.Show(lbl.Text);
    }
}
```